# Skype video captures with green static noise

Tags: video, dell, skype, webcam, 15.04

Recently I've put 64-bit Ubuntu 15.04 on my Dell Inspiron 15 5548. I am experiencing big troubles with the video in Skype. It is capturing with big green static noise, while with other programs such as Cheese, the camera works just fine.

I've been trying to solve this for a few days now, but nothing seems to work.

I've tried pre-loading the video4linux libraries, both the 32 and 64 versions with no luck. With

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

I get `libv4l2: error dequeuing buf: Invalid argument` when I close the test video window.

and with the 64-bit version I get the following error on start-up.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
```

Also I've tried to adjust the settings with `v4l2ucp` and `guvcview` again with no luck. Some adjustments do take effect but the green static remains.

Comment: Lower half of the video is green? Halos around the heads?

Never thought that something is wrong with my system. It's just a usual MS attitude.